# Can't understand linear time method for Stock span using C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I found out this code on geeksforgeeks and it works. But I have a few doubts.Inthe function calculateSpan(), in the following line, `while (!st.empty() && price[st.top()] < price[i])`.. we want to compare the value of the ith element in the array with the element on stack top,but `st.top()` gives the "value" of the element on stack top, not the "index" value of stack top, so why does the line`price[st.top()]`still work. Also in the last line of calculateSpan() function, `st.push(i)` is used to push the current element on to the stack, as mentioned but shouldn't this push the value of 'i' on stack top instead. How does this code work? I've posted the full code. Thanks in advance.
`

```
// a linear time solution for stock span problem
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


void calculateSpan(int price[], int n, int S[])
{
// Create a stack and push index of first element to it
    stack<int> st;
    st.push(0);

// Span value of first element is always 1
   S[0] = 1;

 // Calculate span values for rest of the elements
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    // Pop elements from stack while stack is not empty and top of
    // stack is smaller than price[i]
      while (!st.empty() && price[st.top()] < price[i])
       st.pop();

   // If stack becomes empty, then price[i] is greater than all elements
   // on left of it, i.e., price[0], price[1],..price[i-1].  Else price[i]
   // is greater than elements after top of stack

     S[i] = (st.empty())? (i + 1) : (i - st.top());

  // Push this element to stack
    st.push(i);
  }
}

// A utility function to print elements of array
void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

// Driver program to test above function
 int main()
 {
    int price[] = {1, 4, 50, 90, 12, 80};
    int n = sizeof(price)/sizeof(price[0]);
    int S[n];

  // Fill the span values in array S[]
   calculateSpan(price, n, S);

 // print the calculated span values
    printArray(S, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why a `html` tag ? Please remove (unless I really missed something ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Stack `st` defined in the function `calculateSpan()` we are inserting the index of the days `0,1,2,3,4,5` and so when we see `st.top()` the that give the index of the array `price[]` also.

As you mentioned:

> but `st.top()` gives the "value" of the element on stack top, not the "index" value of stack top

Here the "value" of the element on `stack top` itself is the "index" value of the array `price`!  *Make Sense?*

```
while (!st.empty() && price[st.top()] < price[i])
   st.pop();
```

So, in the above code `price[st.top()] < price[i]` means `price[day-index] < price[selected day]`. Remember we pushed day-index inside the stack.

And since we are pushing in the day-index in stack `st` so, I guess the last lines also make sense now where

```
st.pop(i) // i=0,1,2,3,4,5
```

**NOTE:** Never ignore the comments written on the code body! For example I guess you missed that comment!

```
// Create a stack and push index of first element to it
stack<int> st;
st.push(0);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh it helped big time. It's so simple now. The whole problem was because I missed the fact that we were actually pushing array index into the stack. You are right we should not ignore comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The stack st is a stack of elements of type int so st.top() gives an int which obviously should have been inserted by st.push( an int ). here the stack is to contain array indexes (days). the st.top() gives the last array index pushed to st and the st.pop() removes the last one pushed to st.

Not sure if the above implementation considers case when price[ i ] > price[i-2] and price[i-1] < price[i] and < price[i - 2].

Another implementation without stack data structure:

```
S[0] = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {

      if ( price[ i ] >= price[ i - 1 ] )
      {
          S[ i ] = S[ i - 1 ] + 1;
          for ( int j = i - S[i]; price[i] >= price[j] && j >= 0 ; j-- ) //look for prices less than price[i] but greater than price[i-1]
              S[ i ] += 1;
      }
      else
          S[ i ] = 1;
  }
```

Complexity:

The best case is when array is sorted T(n) = n times.

The worst case is when price[i] is greater than all previous prices and price[i-1] is less or equal to all its previous prices:

int price[] = {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11};// n=22

T(n)=1+2+1+4+1+6+1+8+1+10+1+12....+1+ 2 * ( n/2).

There are n/2 loops forming an arithmetic progression with common difference 2 + n/2 times where there is only 1 instruction ( case when price[i] < price[i-1]).

T(n) then would be n/2 + n/4 * [ ( 2*2 + 2 * ( (n/2) - 1 ) ] = n/2 + n/4 * (  2 + n ) = **n + [ (n^2) / 4 ]**.  This is when n is Even. When n is Odd it becomes **1 + n/2 + [ (n^2) / 4 ]**